# Не определяется размер TextView во фрагменте

Tags: android-viewpager, android, java, textview

Здравствуйте, проблема в том что,getHeight() постоянно возвращает 0. Гуглил, но не нашел рабочее ясное решение....

А вообще задача стоит определения момента, когда текст на экран уже не помещается,вот решил  измерять высоту экрана(работает) и высоту textview ,но тут возникли проблемы.

п.с.Понимаю что когда их измеряю view еще не отрисован,но как тогда измерить...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите колбэки у [`ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html). Например, [`ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html). Соответственно, в нём и делайте все необходимые расчёты/манипуляции.

Comment: Пишу в onCreateView:

 final ViewTreeObserver observer= tvPage.getViewTreeObserver();
    
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
         @Override
         public void onGlobalLayout() {
           tvPage.getHeight();
        //  observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
         }
     });

Но при вызове tvPage.getHeight(); позднее  все равно получаю 0 ,или необходимо всю функцию считывания строки туда положить?